# Is It possible to pass Parameter in data source of CDA

Tags: mdx, pentaho, pentaho-ctools, cda

I have master/slave databases and want to parametrize the URL in data access in cda document 
I want to do something like that if the master is down then changed IP from my web application and route to slave DB or vice versa.
"jdbc:mysql://"+${IP}+"/warehouse_dev"

I don't want to write the same query again and again for different data sources

Answer (score 0):

As far as I undersantd, your talking about the URL value for the nonXMLBody element. As far as I know the standard do not define any parameters notation, and may be the best solution is to manage it at Network level, using for example a load balancer ore some network solution that offers this service.
Hope useful.
Martí